# How can I use setState() to modify a multidimensional array in React Native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, react-native, multidimensional-array

I'm currently trying to add a React component into the third layer of my multidimensional array. My structure is as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        /**
         * The state variables pertaining to the component.
         * @type {Object}
         */
        this.state = {
            structure : [ // Block
                [ // Slot 1
                    [ // Layer 1
                        <Text>text 1</Text>, // Text1
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        };
}
```

`this.state.structure` contains an array for the `slots`, which contains an array for the `layers` which contains an array consisting of `Text` components.

I've tried to use both `concat()` and `push()` to try to set the `structure` array, but both give me errors like "cannot read property of undefined", etc. This is my current `addText()` function:

```
addText() {
        this.setState((previousState) => ({
            structure : previousState.structure[0][0].concat(<Text>text2</Text>),
        }));
}
```

The `addText()` function is called upon pressing a button in my application.

I'm also rendering my array of `Text` components on the current layer directly through the array:

```
{ this.state.structure[0][0] }
```

I feel like I'm staring the problem directly in the face, but have no idea what's causing the issue. I'm expecting to be able to add another `Text` to the container, but nothing I've tried to do seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, you really should *NOT* store instances of React components directly in `state`. Doing so is just asking for trouble down the line, as rendering, state updates, `key` management and data persistence get more and more difficult to wrangle.

Instead, store a *model* of your components in `state`, generally in the form of the props they should have. Then, at render time is when you translate those models into React components:

```
    this.state = {
        structure : [ // Block
            [ // Slot 1
                [ // Layer 1
                    "text 1", // Text1
                ]
            ]
        ],
    };

    render() {
        return this.state.structure[0][0].map(ea => <Text key={ea}>{ea}</Text>);
    }
```

Doing it this way is better because: what happens if you want to read or modify the contents of your "layer" arrays? If they are text values you can simply read/modify the text. But if they are instantiated React components... there is basically no way to effectively update your state without jumping through tons of hoops.

On to your specific problem: the issue is that when you evaluate a statement like this:

```
previousState.structure[0][0].concat(<Text>text2</Text>)
```

the `concat()` function actually returns the value of the array after concatenation. And the value of that array is (in this case) now `[<Text>text 1</Text>, <Text>text2</Text>]`. So, you are actually updating the value of your `state.structure` field to an entirely different array. I'm guessing the error you are seeing - "cannot read property of undefined" - is because when you try to access `this.state.structure[0][0]` you are trying to access it as if it were a two dimensional array but it is now in fact a one dimensional array.

As another replier put it much more succinctly: you are entirely replacing `state.structure` with the contents of `state.structure[0][0]` (after concatenation).

Updating deeply nested data structures in React state is super tricky. You basically want to copy all of the original data structures and change only parts of it. Fortunately, [with ES6 "spread" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals) we have a shorthand for creating new arrays with all of the same items, plus new ones:

```
addText() {
    this.setState((previousState) => {
        // Copy the old structure array
        const newStructure = [...previousState.structure];
        // Update the desired nested array by copying it, plus a new item
        newStructure[0][0] = [...newStructure[0][0], "text2"];

        this.setState({structure: newStructure});
    });
}
```

Main takeaways:

1. Don't store React components in state! Store raw data and use it at render time.
2. Be careful about what you are updating `state` to - it needs to be the SAME state plus a few updates, not the result of some atomic operation.
3. Read up a bit on how array operations like `concat()` and `push()` actually work and what their return values are.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer! It solved my issue perfectly. I have to thank you for giving me tips on what types of data to store in my component states; this is a mistake I've made on a few other components, but after fixing them, I've noticed a huge change in performance as well. Thank you very much, @jered.

Comment: @Gumptastic Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into any philosophy about whether you should do it the way you're doing it, the fundamental problem is that you're replacing `structure` with `structure[0][0]` in your state.

```
{
  // this line sets the whole structure to structure[0][0]:
  structure : previousState.structure[0][0].concat(<Text>text2</Text>),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont agree with this arr structure, and hooks, with an object seems much more conventional, but it could be your this binding.  as ray said below structure[0][0] is replacing the state.
if your using addText Method it needs to be bound to the class. If its not using arrow syntax, it will show as undefined as it is not bound, and will result in undefined. Hope it helps

for example

```
   class App extends React.Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
    };
    this.addText = this.addText.bind(this);
  }
  addText() {
        this.setState((previousState, props) => ({
            structure : previousState.structure[0][0].concat(<Text>text2</Text>),
        }));
}
// ES6
  addTextEs6 = () => {
    this.setState((previousState, props) => ({
      structure : previousState.structure[0][0].concat(<Text>text2</Text>),
  }));
  } 
}

//ES6 
/* Also you do not need to use concat you can use the spread Op. ... See MDN Spread Op`
```

Comment: This still includes the original problem, which is that `structure` is getting replaced entirely with `structure[0][0]`.